# Back Up - Free Drive Space

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, backup, disk-space

Is there a way to know the free disk space available on the drive that the back up file will be created?

For example, SQL Server is installed in Server 1 and the back up file is scheduled to be created in network \server2.

Is there a way to know the free space of \server2?

If I execute `xp_fixeddrives`, it will only give drive space where the current instance is.

While `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` will only give drives where database_files are located.

Comment: is your question limited to t-sql? how about creating a powershell script to get the disk free space?

Comment: yes it is. do you have a snippet for that? of using xp_cmdshell is sufficient?

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159341/how-to-get-disk-capacity-and-free-space-of-remote-computer.

Comment: You could use an external process (maybe one that already monitors disk space on all servers/drives) and have it log that information to a table whenever it runs. The nice thing there is that the process has access to SQL Server instead of all the hoops you'll need to go through to give SQL Server access to the remote file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `XP_CMDSHELL` and issue a simple `DIR` command and load the information into a table variable.  Then, delete the rows that don't have the word *free* and you should get the line that indicates the amount of free space.

```
DECLARE @DirectoryInfo TABLE (TextLine VARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @DirectoryInfo
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir <YourRemoteDirectory>'

DELETE
FROM @DirectoryInfo
WHERE isnull(TextLine, '') NOT LIKE '%free%'

SELECT *
FROM @DirectoryInfo
```

---

`16 Dir(s)  6,247,769,628,672 bytes free`

Comment: Thanks @scott. This snippet can be a good start for what I am looking for.